# React-native TabNavigator inside StackNavigator, cannot move between screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

I am using react-navigation with my react-native app. I have to put TabNavigators inside StackNavigator to use the built in header feature. See below.

app.js

```
const FeedScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  Feed: {
    screen: feed,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Feed"
    }
  }
});

const ProfileScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  Feed: {
    screen: profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "My Profile"
    }
  }
})

const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: { screen: FeedScreenStack },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreenStack }
});

const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Home: TabStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);
```

feed.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

class feed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
               ...
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default feed;
```

When clicking on `profile`, the app can move to profile screen. But it will not move to feed screen when clicking on `feed`. There are no warnings or errors, the app simply does not respond to when I click on feed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined repeted route names at many places, try giving different names

Do it like this

```
const FeedScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  FeedStack: {
    screen: feed,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Feed"
    }
  }
});

const ProfileScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  ProfileStack: {
    screen: profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "My Profile"
    }
  }
})

const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: { screen: FeedScreenStack },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreenStack }
});

const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Home: TabStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);
```